# Can't execute Puppeteer in Node.JS using Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile, puppeteer

I am trying to run a Node.js app that uses Puppeteer in a Docker image.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```docker
FROM node:slim

# We don't need the standalone Chromium
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install Google Chrome Stable and fonts
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the browser work with Puppeteer.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
    wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14.2022.09.09.11
# Create working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Expose app
EXPOSE 6060

# Run app
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Here is the puppeteer code:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: "new",
  executablePath: "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
  args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"],
});
```

And here are the commands that I run:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t puppeteer-backend .
```

```
docker run --rm -p 6060:6060 puppeteer-backend
```

The image builds fine, it also runs fine, and I test that other parts of the app are working, but executing the puppeteer code throws the following error:

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
[77:77:0621/204259.813010:ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(313)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
[39:86:0621/204259.935395:ERROR:file_path_watcher_inotify.cc(315)] inotify_init() failed: Function not implemented (38)
[39:89:0621/204259.960811:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0621/204300.029954:ERROR:scoped_ptrace_attach.cc(27)] ptrace: Function not implemented (38)
Assertion failed: p_rcu_reader->depth != 0 (/qemu/include/qemu/rcu.h: rcu_read_unlock: 101)


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at ChildProcess.onClose (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/src/launch.ts:398:11)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:523:35)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
```

I looked into puppeteer's docs and no luck running that Docker image too. Other tutorials like this [one](https://dev.to/cloudx/how-to-use-puppeteer-inside-a-docker-container-568c) were more helpful, but I still have the same error.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you find any solution?